# unable to perform CRUD in JSON-SERVER

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, json-server

I am trying to add, update, delete in JSON server with Redux Axios. But I am unable to perform CRUD action. I am always getting an error 404. I am using the following code example.  this my db.json

```
 {
   "orderdetails": [
     {
       "OrderID": 111,
       "CustomerID": "VINET",
       
     }
 ]
}
```

I am using the following code for importing Axios from redux. Please find my server.js

```
import axios  from 'axios';
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3007/",
  headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
})
```

I am using the following code example for performing CRUD action in the JSON-Sever. But, I am got a error

```
import http from "../serverapi";
      create(data) {
        return http.post("/orderdetails/posts", data);
      }
    
      update(id, data) {
        return http.put(`/orderdetails/${id}`, data);
      }
    
      delete(id) {
        return http.delete(`/orderdetails/${id}`);
      }
```

[image: updateissue]
[image: adding-issue]

could you please provide the suggestion?

Comment: I guess you didn't create the rout to the API, axios is used to do promise not api rest (I mean it's not the first usage), for that you should use express in back to create a server and define the routing of the backend

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the json-server npm package, there are a couple of problems with your usage.
First, you db.json is invalid. It should be somewhat like this:

```
{
    "orderdetails": [
      {
        "OrderID": 111,
        "CustomerID": "VINET"
        
      },
      {
        "OrderID": 12,
        "CustomerID": "VINET"
        
      }
  ]
}
```

Make sure to check the API url in the browser first.

Second, json-server by default runs on localhost:3000 (Not sure if it can be changed, check the docs here https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server). Your API is pointing to port 3007 as seen here `baseURL: "http://localhost:3007/`,

Lastly, you cannot do a request like `http://localhost:3000/orderdetails/111`. The last part in the api url by default corresponds to the `id` key in db.json, but since your key is `OrderID`, your API end point should be modified to `http://localhost:3000/orderdetails?OrderID=111`. Try this url in your browser, it should return the correct object.

**UPDATE**
Update operations in json-server require the `id` key to be present in the db.json file. Hence, update your db.json as follows:

```
{
    "orderdetails": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "OrderID": 111,
        "CustomerID": "VINET"
        
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "OrderID": 12,
        "CustomerID": "VINET"
        
      }
  ]
}
```

Then, you can try running a POST request on the url `http://localhost:3000/orderdetails` and json body :

```
{
    "OrderID": 12333,
    "CustomerID": "VINET"
  }
```

This will create a new object in the db, with incremented id. PUT, DELETE requests can be made using the id param in the url like `http://localhost:3000/orderdetails/3`.

Comment: Hi @Ankit, actually i change my port number in  my package.json. I getting a details http://localhost:3000/orderdetails?OrderID=111. but I am unable to perform post , put. i am getting same error . 404

Comment: actually i am configure the JSON-server https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: @J.M.Farook I have updated my answer, it should explain it better now.